# Library function not found in Solidity Smart Contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I have created a project for a DApp in Solidity language for Ethereum with this structure:

...ReinsuranceProject
.....contract
.......Reinsure.sol
.....library
.......Strings.sol

In the contract Reinsure.sol I have imported Strings.sol which is a library, like this:
 **`import "../Strings.sol";`**
This library contains a function which converts bytes to string. 
In my main contract, Reinsure.sol I have added these rows:
**`using StringsLib for bytes;`** (StringLib its because the library itself is called like this not the file) 
and in another method I want to return **`varBytes.toString();`**

However, when compiling the project I get this error:

*TypeError: Member "toString" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in bytes memory\n*

The method toString is declared like so:

```
function toString(bytes32 x) constant internal returns (string)
```

Compiler version of Solidity `pragma solidity "0.4.25";`(I am using Visual Studio Code which has an extention for Solidity)

Questions are: If the problem is in the import, what is the right way to import the Strings.sol library with the specified project structure?
If not, am I naming the classes in the wrong way and if so how to fix it?
Is there a way to make a config file for the paths to make this easier?

I would really appreciate your help, and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing types. `bytes` is a dynamic array while `bytes32` is static. Change `using StringLib for bytes` to `using StringLib for bytes32`.

Example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

library StringsLib {
    function toString(bytes32 self) constant internal returns (string) {
        // Convert bytes32 to string
    }
}
```

Contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

import "./StringsLib.sol";

contract LibraryClient {
    using StringsLib for bytes32;

    function doSomething(bytes32 x) public constant returns (string) {
        return x.toString();
    }
}
```